# Abstract method not getting mocked

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

I have a setup similar to this simplified example (should work by copypasting it directly), but the method I want to mock `Controller->setModel()` is not being mocked. No errors appear either:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// Implementation
class Model
{
    // The constructor here would receive a PDO, but that's not important
    public $data = [
        ['id' => 1, 'text' => 'nope'],
        ['id' => 2, 'text' => 'no'],
        ['id' => 3, 'text' => 'not']
    ];

    public function getItem($id)
    {
        // And here we would query with the PDO instead, but again
        // the question is more about mocking the setModel() method
        return $this->data[$id];
    }
}

abstract class Endpoint
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "\n1. Calling abstract class constructor\n";
        $this->model = $this->setModel();
    }

    abstract protected function setModel();
}

class Controller extends Endpoint
{
    public function getStuff($id)
    {
        echo "3. Getting stuff from controller\n";
        $data = $this->model->getItem($id);
        return ['id' => $data['id'], 'text' => $data['text']];
    }

    protected function setModel()
    {
        echo "2. Setting ACTUAL model of controller\n";
        $config = 'sqlite:myfile.sqlite3'; // Suppose this file exists and is valid
        $pdo = new \PDO($config);
        return new Model($pdo);
    }
}

// Test
final class ControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $mockModel = \Mockery::mock('FakeModel')
            ->shouldReceive('getItem')
            ->andReturn(['id' => 123, 'text' => 'myCustomText']);

        $mock = \Mockery::mock('Controller')->makePartial()
            ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
        $mock->shouldReceive('setModel')->andReturn($mockModel);

        $controller = new Controller();
        $result = $controller->getStuff(2);
        $this->assertEquals('myCustomText', $result['text']);
    }
}
```

The test result is as follows. The PDOException is because the php5-sqlite driver is not available any more for my my local VM (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm using a Docker image for the setup, but the same mock issue happens in that too. But that's not the point - the point is to mock `setModel()`:

```
1. Calling abstract class constructor
2. Setting ACTUAL model of controller


Time: 110 ms, Memory: 7.25MB

There was 1 error:

1) ControllerTest::testExample
PDOException: could not find driver

/home/juha/koodaus/pastes/backend/test/Foo/FooTest.php:45
/home/juha/koodaus/pastes/backend/test/Foo/FooTest.php:26
/home/juha/koodaus/pastes/backend/test/Foo/FooTest.php:63

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

As you can see from the 2nd debug print - `Setting ACTUAL model of controller` - the mock is completely ignored. No errors or warnings appear either. What is wrong with the mock setup?

I also tried with `overload` and `alias`, but they don't work, even with:

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

Resulting in:

```
Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock Controller, class already exists
```

But I think that is a known issue.

Versions (legacy setup that doesn't support PHP 7):

PHP 5.6.40
PHPUnit 5.7.27
Mockery 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are able to set up your mock the way that you want. The construct method is being called when you are calling ->makePartial() or ->make or ->getMockForAbstractClass(). so $this->setModel(); always returns null.

I would suggest this solution.

```
public function testExample()
{

    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Controller::class)
            ->setMethods(['setModel'])->getMock();

    $mockModel = \Mockery::mock('FakeModel');
    $mockModel->shouldReceive('getItem')
            ->andReturn(['id' => 123, 'text' => 'myCustomText']);

    $mock->method('setModel')->willReturn($mockModel);

    $mock->instuctModel();

    $result = $mock->getStuff(2);
    $this->assertEquals('myCustomText', $result['text']);
}
```

And The endPoint Abstract class should change to the following one

```
abstract class Endpoint
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "\n1. Calling abstract class constructor\n";
    }

    public function instuctModel(){

        $this->model = $this->setModel();
    }

    abstract public function setModel();
}
```